# If Trump was bad for science, why hasn't the rankings of universities based in the US worsened?

Tags: politics, multidisciplinary, discrimination

Follow-up question to If Brexit is bad for British science, why hasn't the rankings of British universities worsened?

For example, Berkeley for engineering and technology even managed to surpass Singapore's NTNU, going from the 6th place to the 5th, under the last 2 years of Trump's presidency (QS ratings).

Regarding Natural Science, both US and UK universities outperformed Japanese Tokyo University, which slide out of the top 10 in the same time-window.

Comment: How do you expect the answers to be different compared to the orginal thread about the UK leaving the EU?

Comment: @StephanZ. good question. I hope someone will come with the follow-up "If <XYZ> was good for science, why hasn't the rankings of universities based in <XYZ-affected country> improved?"

Comment: @EarlGrey people will not ask that follow-up, because the answer is clear and uniform. The UK university rankings haven't (yet) imploded due to Brexit, because rankings move very slowly. The USA university rankings haven't (yet) imploded due to Trump, because rankings move very slowly. The [country X] university ranking haven't (yet) improved due to [cause Y], because rankings move very slowly. There is no point in keeping spelling that out for individual countries, because the rankings will continue to react very slowly to current affairs.

Comment: I mean there are exceptions where something big enough happens quickly where you would see it in the rankings (Russia 1991, Germany 1930s).  You also might see bigger effects in smaller countries that aren’t already atop the rankings, like Hungary, Lebanon, or maybe even Turkey.  And of course Kabul University.

Comment: I'm downvoting because you didn't cite anything for why you think Trump was bad for science. This matters because if the premise is false the rest of the sentence does not matter; furthermore if the premise is true then there are still different ways to interpret how Trump was for science - e.g. if he publicly denies climate change, that is arguably bad for science, but it doesn't directly affect the things that go into university rankings.

Comment: @Allure I do not need to explain the obvious. Anyhow, I put a big "if" in front, that is to be taken as an axiom, not an opinion, the question then follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the ranking of the university (at least in the ideal world) depends on its performance, not on the support (or lack thereof) the society provides to it. Neither Trump, nor brexit directly changed the faculty composition, curriculum, or the student body at any of the US or British institutions. The incentives or punishments the government or the general public (right now you have to take into account both forces, at least in the US) impose on the educational institutions can change all three, of course, but it requires noticeable time, so the performance will react to them with delay and rankings will react to performance with delay as well, because they normally take into account the last x years, not the current second. So, just wait a bit to see the real effects of brexit and make sure Trump holds power for 10-15 years in a row to see the effects of Trump. Rankings are not stock market prices that are driven by changes in anticipation and react to any event immediately.

So, if you want to check your premise that something is good/bad for science using rankings as an observable, make sure that you maintain that something for a reasonably long time before taking measurements. The brexit will, probably, last though the particular economic hardships it caused may go away (after all, Great Britain is still a strong country). Will Trump last? All you can do here is to vote for him and for the change in the US law that would allow him to stay in power for more than one extra term. I doubt you'll find enough supporters for either of those ideas :-)

Answer (score 3):

US universities are mostly private or run by *states*.  The federal government has very little direct influence on universities relative to what happens in other countries.  And most of the big ways that the federal government influences universities didn’t significantly change during the Trump administration (no giant cuts to NSF or NIH funding).  There were some decisions that had enormous negative impacts on specific scientists (most notably the incredibly cruel travel ban for Iranian scientists working in the US) but not much that you’d expect to dramatically move the needle broadly.  Certainly nothing at the level of Brexit.

Comment: There's also the fact that Trump is no longer president. [See](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-02800-9) *Much of the damage to science — including regulatory changes and severed international partnerships — can and probably will be repaired if Trump loses this November.* Looking at that article it doesn't seem like Trump did much that directly impacts the factors looked at in university rankings either - things like CO2 emissions don't directly affect rankings.

Comment: Right, I mean the main damage was mostly damage to the US's reputation, which hurts recruitment.  For example, it's becoming less common for top German scientists to consider jobs in the US rather than Germany.  I know a number of people (both American and Canadian) who have moved from the US to Canada.  But there are so many good candidates and so few positions anywhere, that the effects are all going to be pretty small.  Honestly the first place you might see an effect in rankings is Canadian universities moving up (and Dutch and Irish universities moving up in Europe).